# Can xxd be used to output the binary representation of hex number , not a string?

Tags: bash, conversion, binary

I would like to generate a raw binary packet from hex in the command line for the purpose of testing a protocol. I'm hoping its simpler to do it this way than writing an aplication.

Here is what currently happens:

```
echo '0A' | xxd  -b
0000000: 00110000 01000001 00001010
```

What i would like to have is:

```
echo '0A' | xxd  -b
0000000: 00001010
```

or

```
echo '0A' | xxd  -b
0000000: 01010000
```

Since I'm not jet sure about the required endianess. I would like to be able to change it when necessary.
Is this achievable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`echo '0A'` produces three characters: <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>NL</kbd>; `xxd -b` will then print those three characters in binary. If you wanted just the single byte whose value is 10 (i.e. hexadecimal `A`), you could write (in bash):

```
echo -n $'\x0A'
      ^ ^  ^
      | |  |
      | |  +-- `\x` indicates a hexadecimal escape
      | +----- Inside a $' string, escapes are interpreted
      +------- -n suppresses the trailing newline
```

A better alternative would be `printf '\x0A'`; printf interprets escape sequences in the format string, and does not output implicit newlines. (For a completely Posix-compatible solution, you would need an octal escape: `printf '\012'`. `printf` should work on any Posix-compatible shell but hexadecimal escapes are an extension.) Yet another bash possibility is `echo -n -e '\x0A'`; the (non-standard) `-e` flag asks echo to interpret escape sequences.

`echo '0A' | xxd  -b` won't output the equivalent of hex `0A`, because `xxd` doesn't know that you intend `0A` to be a hex number rather than two characters. It just takes its input as a series of characters, regardless of what those characters are.

Endianness does not affect bytes. The order of bits inside a byte is entirely conceptual until the byte is transmitted over a serial line and even then it is only visible with an oscilloscope or something similar.

Comment: Sorry about the `50`. It's a typo. Fixing it now

Answer (score 7):

If you want the binary output for a string of hex digits, `xxd -r -p`. E.g.:

```
 $ echo '0A0B0C0D' | xxd -r -p | xxd -b
 0000000: 00001010 00001011 00001100 00001101                    ....
```

converts 0A0B0C0D into a four bytes of binary (first call to xxd), and then converts it back to be printable (second call). You say you want a binary output, but the examples you're trying for are a printable representation.

I don't know of anything where endianness is ambiguous at the nibble level, as you imply in your second example. The conversion in xxd is a pure byte at a time, not assuming they represent any particular multi-byte number.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `xxd` to do that, but you may not like the input format. From your example, 0x0a is the hex value of an ASCII newline. You can create a file with a single newline in it, then use `xxd` to create the listing:

```
$ xxd one_line_file
0000000: 0a                                       .
```

You can get a single newline out of `xxd` from that output if you give it the proper flags:

```
$ echo "0000000: 0a" | xxd -r > another_one_line_file
$ xxd another_one_line_file
0000000: 0a
```

`xxd` has a pretty nice output format, I don't think it would be too onerous to create your packets using a text editor, then use `xxd -r` to go to binary.
                                      .